# Привязка таксономии к произвольному типу записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим имеется страница настройки произвольного типа new_type в админке.
Как для этого типа new_type можно назначить новую таксономию?
Если быть точнее, то на этой странице настроек есть список зарегистрированных таксономий с флажками для их выбора. И при submit формы нужно назначить выбранный тип для new_type. Обработка action формы находится на этой же странице.
Читал про функцию register_taxonomy_for_object_type, но её нужно вызывать при хуке init, а ведь страница загружается до этого хука init.
Как правильно привязать таксономию к типу new_type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типу записей таксономию нужно назначить внутри хука init, да. Только никто не обязывает, чтобы это произошло по нажатию кнопки submit. Надо записать выбор пользователя на админ-странице в опцию (ну, как обычно). А при **следующем обновлении** страницы или переходе на сайт в хуке init прочитать эту опцию и использовать register_taxonomy_for_object_type().

Comment: >Надо записать выбор пользователя на админ-странице в опцию (ну, как обычно)

Comment: если бы я знал, как обычно это делается, то скорее всего я не создавал бы эту тему

Comment: подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы опять уезжаете в другой вопрос. Здесь речь о привязке таксономии. Я ответил. Не знаете, как создавать страницы опций - создайте вопрос. Хотя раньше вы писали, что понимаете, как это делать.

Comment: >Типу записей таксономию нужно назначить внутри хука init, да. Только никто не обязывает, чтобы это произошло по нажатию кнопки submit.

Comment: Вам страница опций зачем вообще? Для красивых полей и окошек? Основное предназначение этой страницы в том, что она **сохраняет** введенные значения.

Comment: как понять никто не обязывает? При чём здесь обязывает?! Ведь выбрать нужную таксономию можно только на странице настроек. 
При чём здесь обязывает?

Comment: >Вам страница опций зачем вообще?

Comment: это совсем другой вопрос. Я создаю плагин, для произвольного типа записи нужна страница настроек. Что в этом может быть удивительного, что для custom-записи нужна страница настроек?

Comment: >Не знаете, как создавать страницы опций - создайте вопрос.

Comment: знаю, но вопрос не про это, а про то, как привязать новую таксономию для произвольного типа на странице настроек. Если бы не знал, то я бы не задал такой вопрос

Comment: Я вам ответил исчерпывающе. Если вы зададите себе труд подумать над тем, что тут написано, все получится.

Comment: >Я вам ответил исчерпывающе.

Comment: >Надо записать выбор пользователя на админ-странице в опцию (ну, как обычно)

Comment: если бы я знал как обычно это делается, я бы не создавал эту тему

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57993/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).